# Flask-Migrate "ModuleNotFoundError"

Tags: python, database, flask, importerror, migrate

I'm trying to make migrations on my Flask api based on SQLite db. Here is my project structure

```
├── app.py
├── blueprints
├── conf.py
├── db.sqlite
├── __init__.py
├── migrations
├── models.py
└── templates
```

Then i initialize my migrate class in the `app.py`

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from conf import ErrorResponses, SuccessResponses

# initialization
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
from models import User, db, BlackListToken

# extensions
from flask_migrate import Migrate
mig = Migrate(app, db)
```

But it fails on importing from custom modules while `flask db migrate -m "rm id and made name/surname nullable"`.

```
Usage: flask db migrate [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "api_flask.app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/zahessi/all/bubbie_D/api_flask/app.py", line 9, in <module>
    from conf import ErrorResponses, SuccessResponses
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conf'
```

Here is how `models.py` looks:

```
from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    username = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(32))
    surname = db.Column(db.String(32))
    public_id = db.Column(db.String(32))
    creation_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    ...
```

When I remove all imports from custom py files, all seems to work, however, this is a lot of unnecessary work. Do you have any suggestions why does it work in that way?

UPD: Added `conf.py`. It fails on every local import, on blueprints as well, depending on the order of the imports.

```
from re import findall

class ErrorResponses:
    usernameOrPasswordBlank = {
        "success": False,
        "error": "Username and password cannot be blank."
    }
    userAlreadyExists = {"success": False, "error": "Such user already exists"}
    incorrectData = {
        "success": False,
        "error": "Incorrect username or password"
    }
    invalidData = {
        "success": False,
        "error": "Username or password is invalid"
    }
    noUser = {
        "success": False,
        "error": "There is no user with such username or public_id"
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Can you show conf.py file?

Comment: looks like your conf file causes the issue, post it's contents.

Comment: @needtobe added conf.py, but it doesn't have anything extraordinary. It's only classes with ready-to-send responses. It works properly with any other part of the project.

Comment: @ikuamike added conf.py, explanation in the prev comment

Comment: Perhaps instead of using flask cli, try using flask_script. What I mean i suggest you create `manage.py` in root directory and add there `from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand`, `from flask_script import Manager`, `migrate = Migrate(app, db)`, `manager = Manager(app)`, `manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)`

Comment: Then you can simply just `python manage.py db migrate` or `python3 manage.py migrate` (depends on PATH).

Comment: Also try removing conf from the imports in app.py just to test if problem is the conf file. `from models import User, db, BlackListToken` I also see this in your app.py file remove the db from imports and make it `from models import User, BlackListToken` because there is no db in models

Comment: @needtobe thanks a lot, that solved the problem with imports, god bless you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem I will suggest using flask_script instead flask cli. Simply create manage.py file in your root directory and then do as follows:

```
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
```

To launch migration simply do:
`python manage.py db migrate` or `python3 manage.py migrate` (depends on your PATH configuration)

Answer (score 5):

I can see that you solved the problem, but I want to show you the simpler solution than installing `flask-script` and creating `manage.py` file. You just have to delete `__init__.py` file that is at the same level as app.py file. It solved the problem for me. Cheers :)

Comment: This was my problem...  Wish I found this sooner.  Thank you for posting this @Mikey...

Answer (score 0):

To the accepted answer, have in mind that Flask_Script is not longer supported. A better solution would be to just delete the `__init__.py` file from your root directory and simply run the flask cli `flask db upgrade`.