# Flask-migrate can't find custom modules

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I've made some changes to my SQLAlchemy models and I want to migrate them to my db. When I try to migrate, I get the following error:

```
$ flask db migrate
Usage: flask db migrate [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "minerva.dashboard.app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mattfred/Minerva/envs/dashboard/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/mattfred/Minerva/minerva/dashboard/app.py", line 13, in <module>
    from templates.nav_layout import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'templates'
```

I don't know what has changed since I first initialized the db, other than moving the views into separate files instead of 1.

I can actually resolve this by changing the import statement to

```
from .templates.nav_layout import *
```

but then I get this error when trying to run the app:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .templates.nav_layout import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.templates'; '__main__' is not a package
```

I've tried the solution presented here: [Flask-Migrate "ModuleNotFoundError"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925284/flask-migrate-modulenotfounderror)

but that runs with no errors and doesn't change my db.

If I remove that line, it just moves to the next templates file and then the Config file, so I don't think there's anything wrong with the templates file.

```
# app.py
import os

from flask import Flask, redirect
from flask_login import login_required, LoginManager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, disconnect

from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware

from dash import Dash

from templates.nav_layout import *
from templates.dash_app_layout import *

from Config import Config, DEBUG

# Setup the Flask server
server = Flask(__name__)
server.config.from_object(Config)

db = SQLAlchemy(server)
migrate = Migrate(server, db)

@server.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
    from Models import Users, Company
    return {'db': db, 'Users': Users, 'Company': Company}
```

I'm fairly certain this has something to do with the project structure

```
├── app.py
├── Config.py
├── Forms.py
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── migrations/
├── Models.py
├── requirements.txt
├── templates
│   ├── change_profile.html
│   ├── dash_app_layout.py
│   ├── default_login.html
│   ├── default_logout.html
│   ├── _formhelpers.html
│   ├── header.html
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── nav_layout.py
│   ├── record_meeting.html
│   ├── register_user.html
│   ├── upload_meeting.html
│   └── voice_enroll.html
├── utils
│   ├── audio_processor
│   │   ├── AudioProcessor.py
│   │   ├── audio_type_converter.py
│   │   ├── Deidentifier.py
│   │   ├── Identification
│   │   │   ├── CreateProfile.py
│   │   │   ├── DeleteProfile.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── Utterance.py
│   │   └── voice_enroll.py
│   ├── db_operations.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── interim_result_processor.py
│   └── utils.py
└── views
    ├── auth.py
    ├── dash_callbacks.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── meeting_upload.py
    ├── profile.py
    └── record_meeting.py
```

Comment: What was your current directory? There is nothing called `minerva/dashboard/app.py` in the file structure that you presented. I think you are missing parent directories. Please provide the complete structure.

Comment: The fine structure I've shown is from dashboard. Minerva has two separate webapps that are unrelated. It's not part of the project. App.py etc. are all in the dashboard folder and have no dependencies outside of that (other than the environment).

Comment: I repeat my question. What was your current directory? And one more question: What's the value of your `FLASK_APP` environment variable?

Comment: My current directory was ```/home/mattfred/Minerva/minerva/dashboard``` as in app.py is ```/home/mattfred/Minerva/minerva/dashboard/app.py``` and ```FLASK_APP=app.py```. Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: I don't understand why the error message mentions "minerva.dashboard.app". How does it know about the minerva and dashboard parents if you are starting from inside the dashboard directory? Do you have a custom PYTHONPATH setting maybe?

Comment: I had an ```__init__.py``` in the minerva directory by accident. I've since removed it and retried running the same commands as above from both the minerva and dashboard directories. It still gives the same error except for ```Error: While importing "minerva.dashboard.app", an ImportError was raised:``` now reads ```Error: While importing "dashboard.app", an ImportError was raised:``` I don't think I have any custom PYTHONPATH settings unless Pycharm changed something without me knowing.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the current directory set by PyCharm is what you think it is? Try doing this w/o PyCharm from the CLI.

Comment: I always run my code from the cli. I don't like to use the pycharm terminal. I did just try it now from the pycharm terminal and got the same error. I really just don't understand how modules work. It seems to be trying to import dashboard.app but only when I run flask db migrate and seems to run fine when I run app.py directly. I'm having another issue trying to push the app to azure that I think might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56352494/flask-app-cant-find-module-when-deployed-to-azure-works-fine-locally/56356003#56356003

Comment: And thank you so much for your help with this and your blog in general. I've read quite a few of your tutorials and they are excellent!

Comment: I just noticed this. Why do you have a `__init__.py` in your project root? Can you remove that and see if you get any different output?

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much. I thought there was supposed to be one there if I wanted to use any of the files in the subdirectories.

Comment: No. The top level directory is normally not a Python package, it should not have a __init__.py as that changes some import rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, the issue was that the top-level directory had a `__init__.py` file. Removing that file addressed the weird import behavior.