# Flask app can't find module when deployed to azure - works fine locally

Tags: python, azure, flask, importerror

Azure gives a module import error but the same code runs perfectly locally.

```
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388004719Z: [ERROR]  Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388027419Z: [ERROR]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388031719Z: [ERROR]      worker.init_process()
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388035419Z: [ERROR]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388039419Z: [ERROR]      self.load_wsgi()
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388043019Z: [ERROR]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388047119Z: [ERROR]      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388050819Z: [ERROR]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388054619Z: [ERROR]      self.callable = self.load()
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388075019Z: [ERROR]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388084919Z: [ERROR]      return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388088619Z: [ERROR]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388092219Z: [ERROR]      return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388095619Z: [ERROR]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388099119Z: [ERROR]      __import__(module)
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388102419Z: [ERROR]    File "/home/site/wwwroot/app.py", line 102, in <module>
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388106219Z: [ERROR]      from views.auth import register_user_bp, user_login_bp, user_logout_bp
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388109619Z: [ERROR]    File "/home/site/wwwroot/views/auth.py", line 4, in <module>
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388113619Z: [ERROR]      from Forms import *
2019-05-29T02:50:47.388116919Z: [ERROR]  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Forms'
```

It seems to find one of my custom modules, but not the one in the root directory from a subdirectory. However, it appears to successfully import Config.py from app.py, which are both in the root directory.

The program runs from app.py in the root directory if that is important

I think there is something about the way that gunicorn/WSGI works that I don't understand. I can't figure out what changes the way imports behave.

```
project_root
├── app.py
├── Config.py
├── Forms.py
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── migrations
├── Models.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
├── templates
│   ├── change_profile.html
│   ├── dash_app_layout.py
│   ├── default_login.html
│   ├── default_logout.html
│   ├── _formhelpers.html
│   ├── header.html
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── nav_layout.py
│   ├── record_meeting.html
│   ├── register_user.html
│   ├── upload_meeting.html
│   └── voice_enroll.html
├── utils
│   ├── audio_processor
│   │   ├── AudioProcessor.py
│   │   ├── audio_type_converter.py
│   │   ├── Deidentifier.py
│   │   ├── Identification
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── Utterance.py
│   │   └── voice_enroll.py
│   ├── db_operations.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── interim_result_processor.py
│   └── utils.py
└── views
    ├── auth.py
    ├── dash_callbacks.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── meeting_upload.py
    ├── profile.py
    └── record_meeting.py
```

I'm not sure why it works fine locally, but can't import from Forms.py when on the webapp. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the file structure, but I can't figure out what and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try move the `Forms.py` to folder `views` or
add these two line in `auth.py`
`import sys`
`sys.path.append('../')`
to add the '../' path to the PYTHONPATH.
Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That directory was already included in sys.patth (from print(sys.path)) but I tried anyway with no luck. Moving Forms.py to forms/Forms.py did get rid of the error, but now the worker just times out with no error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue, then I discovered the issue was possibly caused by missing your project path in the `sys.path`.

I guess that you developed locally in a Python virtual environment, so the `sys.path` will include your project path automatically when you command `source <project_root>/bin/active` to enable virtual environment. But without virtual environment, your project path will not be default imported into the `sys.path` of system Python runtime.

So the solution is that you can manually append `/home/site/wwwroot` to `sys.path` via add new code line into `app.py` as below.

```
from flask import Flask

import sys
sys.path.append('/home/site/wwwroot')

# Then you can normally import Forms module
from Forms import *
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That directory was already included in sys.patth (from print(sys.path)) but I tried anyway with no luck. I also tried the other response above to add '../' to the path, but that didn't work either. Moving Forms.py to forms/Forms.py did get rid of the error, but now the worker just times out with no error messages.